# Linearization by freezing the coefficients of the main part of the PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

> > Let $\Omega\subset C^0$ a bounded domian in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $u\in C^2(\Omega)\cap C(\overline{\Omega})$ be a non negative classical solution of
> >     $$
> > (1+x^2)u_{xx}-2xu_{xy}+(1+u)u_{yy}-(1+u^2)u_x+(1+u_x)u_y-u=1\text{ in }\Omega,\\u(x,y)=\frac{\sin^2(x)}{1+y^2}\text{ on }\partial\Omega.
> > $$
> >     Show that $(0\leq) y\leq 1$ for $(x,y)\in\Omega$.

I already asked this here: [Do I have to use a maximum principle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548972/do-i-have-to-use-a-maximum-principle)

But this time my question concerns a special method for solving this, I think it is called something like *linearization by freezing the coefficients*.

I do not know more about that, but I heard that it works by inserting the assumed solution $u$ in the coefficients of the main part of the PDE and the aim is to get a semi-linear (or linear?) PDE on which one can apply maximum principle.

Do you know something about that method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea behind the "freezing" technique is to introduce a new "source term" $v$ and replace enough appearances of $u$ by $v$ such that the resulting equation is linear - for example in this case we could try

$$F_v(u)=(1+x^2)u_{xx} - 2xu_{xy}+(1+v)u_{yy} - (1+v^2)u_x + (1-v_x) u_y - u - 1= 0.$$(For certain purposes it may be more fruitful to do something else with the first-order term - it's not immediately obvious what the "correct" choice is to me. For the purpose of establishing the maximum principle it doesn't matter.)

A function $u$ is then a solution of the original PDE if and only if $F_u(u) = 0$; i.e. iff it is a solution of the linear PDE $F_u (\cdot)= 0$. In some cases this could give a way to find solutions: if the linear PDE $F_v(u) = 0$ has unique solution given by $u = G(v)$ then solving the non-linear PDE is just solving the fixed-point problem $G(u)=u$.

Whether we establish the existence of solutions in this manner or another, the most useful application comes in analysing these solutions - since $u$ is a solution of the linear PDE $F_u(\cdot)=0$, you can apply all the same a priori estimates you're familiar with from the linear elliptic theory. All you have to do is control the properties of the solution enough for the operator $F_u$ to be elliptic.

In this case, you are given that $u$ is non-negative, so you should be able to verify that $F_u$ is indeed elliptic. Thus the maximum principle holds for $u$.

Comment: Why is the new PDE $F_v(u)$ a linear one?

Comment: @math12: The coefficients of $u, u_i, u_{ij}$ depend only on $x$ and $v(x)$.

Comment: In order to use the maximum principle for linear elliptic PDE, I have to verify if (1) $F_u(\cdot)$ is uniformly elliptic in $\Omega$ and that (2) $a_{11}(x,y)=1+x^2, a_{12}(x,y)=a_{21}(x,y)=-x, a_{22}(x,y)=1+u(x,y), c=-1, f=1$ are in $C(\overline{\Omega})$. (2) is clear because they are all continious on $\mathbb{R}^2$ resp. $u$ is by definition in $C(\overline{\Omega})$. But how can I show (1)? Is it enough to show that the coefficient matrix of the main part is positive definite, i.e. only has positive eigenvalues?

Comment: @math12: for *uniform* ellipticity you need a positive uniform lower bound on the eigenvalues. If you work it through, this should be true because $u\ge 0$ and $\Omega$ (and thus the domain of $x$) is bounded.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know how to do this. I guess I have $\begin{pmatrix}1+x^2-\lambda & -x\\-x & 1+u-\lambda\end{pmatrix}$, the determinant of this is $(1+x^2-\lambda)\cdot (1+u-\lambda)-x^2$ and so I have to solve $(1+x^2-\lambda)\cdot (1+u-\lambda)-x^2=0$. How can I solve this.

Comment: @math12: it's a quadratic equation in $\lambda$, so e.g. apply the quadratic formula.

Comment: I get $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{u+x^2+2}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{(u+x^2+2)^2}{4}-ux^2}$

Comment: I think the eigenvalues are $\geq 1$. Is that right? And then the PDE is uniformly elliptic?

Comment: I got $\frac12 \left( 2 + u + x^2 \pm \sqrt{u^2 + 4x^2 - 2 u x^2 + x^4}\right)$ - check your answer. The eigenvalues can be much less than $1$ if $x$ is large - getting the right bound is pretty hard. You can show $\lambda$ is bounded below by $\frac12 \left(2 + M^2 - M\sqrt{4 + M^2} \right) > 0$ where $M = \sup_\Omega |x|$ - use the concavity of the square root function.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11344/discussion-between-math12-and-anthony-carapetis)

Comment: Could you pls. explain me how you came to the boundary $\frac{1}{2}(2+M^2-M\sqrt{4+M^2})$ and why this is $>0$? I only see that $\frac{1}{2}(2+x^2+u-\sqrt{u^2-2ux^2+x^4+4x^2})\geq\frac{1}{2}(2+x^2-M\sqrt{M^2 + 4})$.

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer and I have learn a lots from it. By the way, could you recommend some references about the 'freezing technique'? Say, are there any books talks about it? Thank you in advance.